# run both android and ios on same project on aws farm device

Tags: appium

I have appium project containing both Android and iOS test cases
like

```
|-- src
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- java
|   |       |-- common
|   |       |-- tests
|   |
|   |-- test
|       |-- java
|           |-- android
|           |-- ios
|-- resources
|-- config
|-- appium-config
```

When I upload the package to Amazon AWS farm device
how can I differentiate between both platforms without creating 2 separate projects